# Remove BitLocker at boot

Tags: windows-10, encryption, lenovo-laptop, bitlocker

I have a Lenovo laptop. When I boot it, I am asked for BitLocker recovery key and am unable to access Windows OS in any form. I don't have either the PIN or the key. I've tried other methods that I read online but to no avail. I don't mind wiping the laptop via Device Media. Is it possible to format the disk to recover the laptop?

Comment: Why don't you have the Bitlocker PIN or recovery key?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, if BitLocker was configured to use software encryption, then yes you can just wipe and reinstall the OS as usual. Booting from e.g. the Windows installation USB stick will let you delete the old partition which was encrypted.

But if the installer doesn't see any partitions, then it might out that BitLocker was using hardware encryption (that is, the SSD's "TCG OPAL" feature). In that case, from what I know you will need to disassemble it and write down the "PSID" that's printed on a sticker on the SSD itself. The PSID can then be given to various programs to "factory reset" the SSD. (If the SSD has no PSID written on it, then you'll need a new SSD.)

Also, don't forget to go to the laptop's firmware setup screen and activate the "Clear TPM" option. This has nothing to do with removing the old BitLocker, but it'll let the TPM be used by the newly installed OS.

Answer (score 0):

Few options you can follow

**1. Using diskpart**

Boot the install media > select 'repair' in from the Windows installation > open cmd

```
diskpart
```

display all the disks of your computer

```
list disk
```

choose the desired disk

> select disk n
> Remove drive's partition, data, and signature

```
clean
```

Now exit dispart; close cmd and resume the installation the normal way

**2. Using gparted/linux**

Boot from any live linux USB > open gparted > delete all the partitions of the target disk
and start your installation